# HTTP request to Wikipedia

Tags: c++, http, wikipedia

I am trying to access a Wikipedia page via socket programming and a C++ script. I am able to reach the server, but get a 404 error informing me that the requested URL does not exist. Just entering the same URL in a browser works fine.

This is the URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

This is the C++ script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s, error;
    char length[10];
    length[0]=0;    

    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if((s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 01: creating socket failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton("204.27.61.92",&addr.sin_addr);

    error = connect(s,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    if(error!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 02: conecting to server failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    char msg[]="GET /wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol HTTP/1.1\nHOST: en.wikipedia.org\n\n"

    int leng = send(s, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    if(leng == -1)
         cout<<"There is a problem!"<<endl;

    send(s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

    char answ[1024];

    ssize_t len;
    while((len = recv(s, answ, 1024, 0)) > 0)
    {
        cout.write(answ, len);
    }
    cout << endl;

    if(len < 0)
    {
        cout<<"Error!"<<endl;
    }

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The script works fine overall. Exchanging the line

```
char msg[]="GET /wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol HTTP/1.1\nHOST: en.wikipedia.org\n\n";
```

with

```
char msg[] = "GET /beej/inet_ntoaman.html http/1.1\nHOST: retran.com\n\n";
```

retrieves the requested web site without error. What am I missing here? Why does the script not work for Wikipedia?

Thanks

Comment: What is 204.27.61.92?

Comment: You might want to use `const std::string msg` instead of the C-style declaration if you're doing C++. Why are you doing this the hard way instead of using a library like `curl`?

Comment: and what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @ Mark & Oliver, thanks for replying. David has pointed out to me that I used the wrong IP address.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Implementing HTTP correctly is an extremly hard task. if it's for studing and experimenting only, then go ahead, if not, use one of the available libraries.

Comment: Just wrting a few small scripts, but hoping to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The IP address you're connecting to is not wikipedia's.
2. Your code claims HTTP 1.1 compliance but doesn't support chunked encoding.
3. You send the request twice for some reason.
4. You seem to expect the server to close the connection after sending you the data, but you didn't ask it to.
5. Your line endings aren't compliant with the HTTP specification.

You can make things a lot easier by trying to implement HTTP 1.0 instead.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice, David. This is getting me a step ahead.

@1 I should have entered the correct IP address. I got a an address for a Wikipedia server:
208.80.153.224
Now I receive a different error message:
`HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect
Server: Varnish
Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 11:15:42 GMT
X-Varnish: 4089075905
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close`
Do you have a clue what that means and what's wrong?

Comment: @2 I do not know how to do this? Is there a snippet of example code you could refer me to?

@3&4 My bad. Thanks for spotting this.

@5 Would this be \r\n ?

Comment: That message doesn't indicate you did anything wrong, other than not handling it. You got a 301, which is a redirect. You need to follow the redirect. For 2, just implement HTTP 1.0 instead of 101. For 5, yes, again, follow the specification.

Comment: And by "follow redirect", that means parsing out the response's `Location` header and then sending a new HTTP request to the specified URL, in this case `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol`.  You are requesting an HTTP (unencrypted) url and Wikipedia is redirecting you to an HTTPS (encrypted) url for the same page.  Which means you now need to add SSL/TLS encryption to your code in order to handle HTTPS.

Comment: @Ips Also, I would add, that if you expect to make sense of the response, you need to write a *lot* more code than you have. With just what you have, there is absolutely no reason for you to expect to be able to make sense of the response. HTTP responses are not always human readable (for example, chunked encoding) and you have code to make sense of the response.

Comment: Thanks, David & Remy, for clarifying all of this. My script is working now!